# Does the new 24" iMac Touch ID keyboard work with Mac's with the T2 Chip?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon, touch-id, t2

I have a 2019 MacBook Air with Touch ID and was wondering if the new 24" iMac Touch ID keyboard will work with my computer. I know for sure that it works with all other Apple Silicon computers, but what about computers with the Apple T2 chip. When I use my Mac with my external monitor my unlock with Apple Watch doesnt always work and putting in the password is hassle especially when I am in a hurry

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Touch ID feature on the new keyboards only works with the M1 chip.

> Implemented wirelessly on Magic Keyboard, it uses a dedicated security component on the keyboard that communicates directly with Secure Enclave in M1, creating an encrypted channel to protect users’ fingerprint data from end to end.

https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2021/04/imac-features-all-new-design-in-vibrant-colors-m1-chip-and-45k-retina-display/?afid=p239%7C10078&cid=aos-us-aff-ir

Comment: Well the T2 chips has a Secure Enclave..

Comment: Yes, but clearly a predecessor not designed to work in this way.

Comment: sooooooooo yes or no, does it, or does it not work? right now, I have marked this answer as correct because it says no. but I am still sensing some doubt.

Comment: @SkylineX The truth is nobody knows beyond the quote I included. I suppose my interpretation could be wrong, and if it is I'll be sure to correct this answer to avoid any confusion. That being said, even without this quote, I'd be surprised if it did work.

Comment: I think that Apple would be able to make it work with the T2 chip, but they don't want to because of marketing and other stuff. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have the standalone version of the keyboard (Magic Keyboard with Touch ID for Mac models with Apple silicon), and I use it with a MacBook Pro 13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports (1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5).

The keyboard's Touch ID does not work. I tried with the cable and wirelessly.

In contrast, when I connect the keyboard to an M1 MacBook Air, the Touch ID does work.

Apple docs have become more explicit over time, as well:

> The Magic Keyboard with Touch ID (and the Magic Keyboard with Touch ID and Numeric Keypad) provides a Touch ID sensor in an external keyboard that can be used with any Mac with Apple silicon.

[Magic Keyboard with Touch ID](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/magic-keyboard-with-touch-id-secf60513daa/web)

> Note: Touch ID and the function keys work as described above for any Mac with Apple silicon and macOS 11.3 or later.

[Magic Keyboard](https://support.apple.com/guide/imac/magic-keyboard-apd0e7983e19/mac#:%7E:text=Note%3A%20Touch%20ID%20and%20the,and%20macOS%2011.3%20or%20later)

Comment: @agarza - thx for cleanup. (I don't know if that's considered static in SE, but I appreciate it)